# How would I return the number of a sentence(s) that contains a word?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get better with programming (specifically c#) and am stuck on this project.

I am trying to create a windows form program where a user inputs a paragraph into a textbox and the program then returns all the unique words in the inputted paragraph as well as the count of unique words. I then need to list what sentence(s) contain these unique words.

I believe I have the first two parts down (listing unique words and their counts) however, I am struggling to think of how to complete the last part. I've listed my code below. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

```
namespace MrSteamyRayVaughn
{
    public partial class MrSteamyRayVaughn : Form
    {
        public string[] paragraphWords { get; set; }
        public string[] paragraphSentences { get; set; }

        public MrSteamyRayVaughn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ParagraphSplitter();
            UniqueWordCounter();
        }

        private void ParagraphSplitter()
        {
            string inputParagraph = richTextBox1.Text;
            paragraphWords = inputParagraph.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            paragraphSentences = inputParagraph.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        private void UniqueWordCounter()
        {
            var uniqueWords = paragraphWords
            .OrderBy(w => w)
            .GroupBy(w => w, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                Word = grp.Key,
                Count = grp.Count()
            }
            );

            foreach (var u in uniqueWords)
            {
               richTextBox1.AppendText($"{Environment.NewLine}Word {u.Word}: Count {u.Count}");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Split into sentences first. Then pull the words _from_ the sentences, not the paragraphs. Having the sentences first allows for association and/or reverse searches. Using `SelectMany` may be helpful, depending on structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and condense your code down to a [mre]. 
We ask for a MRE because (a) it's a waste of time to read through lines after lines of irrelevant code looking for what's wrong, and 
(b) often, the exercise of creating a MRE helps you isolate and identify the problem and helps you fix the issue yourself. Also, please ask a _specific question_ about a problem you're having with your code.

Comment: `var containsAtLeastOneUniqueWord = paragraphSentences.Where(sentence => uniqueWords.Any(sentence.Contains))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Where` clause to filter out sentences where the sentence contains `Any` of the items in `uniqueWords`:

```
List<string> sentencesThatContainAUniqueWord = paragraphSentences
    .Where(sentence => uniqueWords.Any(sentence.Contains))
    .ToList();
```

Or, if you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, you can use the `IndexOf` method, which returns the index of the first match (or `-1` if no matches were found):

```
List<string> sentencesThatContainAUniqueWord = sentences
    .Where(sentence => words.Any(word =>
        sentence.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand what you are trying, but if I do, I will go for a different approach.

The easiest, and obvious way to count the unique words will be just to add each work to a list if they aren't already included, and then count the elements in the list.

Yeah, it's less fancy but It will do the trick and if someone comes after you will understand right away what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am responding to this on my mobile, so apologies in advance on any formatting errors.

I think that if you just say

```
 Dictionary<string,string> uWordSentenceDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
 foreach (string sentence in paragraphSentences) {
     string[] sentenceWords = sentence.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     List<string> matches = sentenceWords.Intersect(uniqueWords).ToList();
     If(matches.Any()) { 
        foreach(string match in matches){
           uWordSentenceDictionary.Add(match,    sentence);
           } 
       }
    }
uWordSentenceDictionary.ForEach( x => {
    Console.Writeline($"Unique word: {x.Key}, Sentence: {x.Value}");
});
```

That would allow you to separate it out nicely I would think. I saw others using contains which will also solve your problem. I'm offering this as an alternative, broken down approach.